# React Router 6.3.0 render component twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm new to React and try to create my first SPA with React Router.
I try to do it with a functional components.
For now it's very basic but even now I faced a problem which I cannot resolve - component renders twice every time I use proper routing.

Problem appeared when I started to use `useEffect` hook to call simple `console.log()` on component initialisation. I noticed every time I choose `Autosearch` from a `Navbar` React Router render proper component but I can see two logs `Called!` in a browser console. I've tried recompose structure of my HTML but it didn't work.

#### index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

#### App.js

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="container-background h-auto">
            <div className="container-lg p-2">
                <Header/>
                <Navbar/>
                <section className="content p-4">{<ContentDisplay/>}</section>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

#### Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <nav className="navbar nav-custom">
                <span className="navbar-collapse">
                    <div className="nav">
                        <NavLink className="nav-item nav-link text-white" to={"/reversed"}>Reversed</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="nav-item nav-link text-white" to={"/autosearch"}>AutoSearch</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="nav-item nav-link text-white" to={"/about"}>About</NavLink>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </nav>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

#### ContentDisplay.js

```
const ContentDisplay = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" exact element={<Home/>} />
                <Route path="/reversed" exact element={<Reversed />} />
                <Route path="/autosearch" exact element={<Autosearch />} />
                <Route path="/about" exact element={<About />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}
```

#### Autosearch.js

```
const Autosearch = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Called!")
    }, []);

    return(
        <>
            Autosearch
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole view hierarchy in your app is child of StrictMode (index.js)

In dev mode a double rendering is the intended behavior.
This does not affect production mode.

https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: I don't know why you had got vote down. I think it's a good answer and I wasn't aware of this. I've did some udemy course but with earlier version of react and hadn't got this problem before.  Indeed when I switched <React.StrictMode> into e.g. <React.Fragment> it stopped rendering component twice. But anyway I will try to keep StrictMode and check some advices how to design components correct.

Comment: @EnGoPy Thx, yes as you have read it helps identifying side effect issues. Like when you call code that should be idempotent in component lifecycle. Enjoy coding :)